# Using a same shortcodes twice on a same page

Tags: wordpress

In woocommerce. I tried to use their shortcodes to show products that are categorized.

```
[product_category category="navigation"]
```

Now I want to use this shortcode twice or more in order to show all products that are categorized from the two categories on a same page. Please take note, all this things should be done inside the wordpress backend not on a php files etc.

For example:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="navigation">
[product_category category="navigation"]
</div>

<div id="communication">
[product_category category="communication"]
</div>

</div>
```

The navigation category successfully shows all the products that are categorized from navigation but on the communication category, it outputs only the text of [product_category category="communication"]

Is there a solution how to use same shortcodes twice on a same page please?

Here's the link for you to understand my problem more:

```
http://192.190.82.124/~sevensea/products/seirim
```

After going to that link, go here:

```
http://192.190.82.124/~sevensea/products/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing about shortcodes and Wordpress that would prevent you from using the same or similar shortcodes multiple times.  I do it all the time using a Wordpress EStore plugin.

Whether it works or not will depend on the implementation. I would suggest that you first create a test page and pare down the content to only what you have shown above, and use a default theme.  If the problem is still present, contact woocommerce.  If you're super handy, you can also sometimes figure out what the problem is by looking at the resulting source code (View Page Source).

Comment: There is, please check this link:
http://192.190.82.124/~sevensea/products/seirim

After clicking that link, go here:
http://192.190.82.124/~sevensea/products/

Comment: On the navigation tab, the shortcode of woocommerce was able to show products that are categorized on navigation but on the communication tab, the shortcode of woocommerce didnt able to do so, instead it gives me a plain text of [product_category category="communication"]

Now you understand the problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same issue and I wish I knew what was the reason for it. It's frustrating.